# Injecting a node into an external Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am a junior developer who lacks experience, so I apologize if my question showcases signs of sheer ignorance. My title may not be expressive of the problem I face, so I shall do my best to be descriptive.

In my project, I am making use of a 3rd party component (a dropdown menu), which I would like to modify in my application. I don't want to fork and edit their code since I would like to pull the latest styling changes since my modification is only slight, being that I would like to add some text next to the dropdown icon.

Here is a (simplified) version of the code.

```
<template>
  <overflow-menu
    ref="overflow_menu"
  >
    <overflow-menu-item
      v-for="item in overflowMenuItems"
      :id="item.id"
      :key="item.name"
    >
      {{ item.tabName }}
    </overflow-menu-item>
  </overflow-menu>
</template>

<script>
import { OverflowMenu, OverflowMenuItem } from '@some-library/vue'; //Don't have control of the implementation of these components.

export default {
  name: 'CustomOverflowMenu',
  components: {
    OverflowMenu,
    OverflowMenuItem,
  },
  props: {
    overflowMenuItems: Array,
    label: String,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.injectOverflowMenuLabel();
  },
  methods: {
    injectOverflowMenuLabel() {
      const overflowMenuElement = this.$refs.overflow_menu.$el.firstChild;
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      const node = document.createTextNode(this.$props.label);
      span.appendChild(node);
      overflowMenuElement.insertBefore(
        span,
        overflowMenuElement.firstChild,
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

It functionally works ok, however, it doesn't seem a particularly elegant solution, and I feel as if I could be doing it in a more "Vuey" way. I also am greeted with a Vue warning of: **Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined**. This ultimately means I am not able to mount my component and unit test my custom overflow menu.

Is there a way to get this functionality, but in a more maintainable manner. I would either like to simplify the logic of the *injectOverflowMenuLabel* function, or perhaps there is a completely alternative approach that I haven't considered.

Would appreciate any help, you lovely people.

Thanks,

Will.

Comment: Use custom directives to inject into that and also extend the original component with your customization and then use it in another component/ view -> prevents messing with child components

Comment: Is this a free lib? Please, specify it instead of `@some-library/vue` and provide a working example that can replicate your case. The problem is specific to this library and should be addressed accordingly. That you get this error means that it doesn't work ok because a part of your code fails.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Could we look at a sketch of this "text next to the dropdown icon"? Also could you try use this dropdown (https://mikerodham.github.io/vue-dropdowns/), which allows you to specify a placeholder text.

Comment: It seems like you're just trying to insert a `span` right before `overflow-menu-item`. You could just do that directly in the template: `<span>{{ label }}</span><overflow-menu-item>...`